# CocoaLibSpotify - Library not loaded

Tags: xcode, cocoa, dylib, cocoalibspotify-2.0, libspotify

I've created a simple mac app that uses the Cocoa wrapper for libspotify.

When I export the project as an Application and try to run it, it crashes immediately.

Crash report:

```
Application Specific Information:
  dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/CocoaLibSpotify.framework/Versions/A/CocoaLibSpotify
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/Wunderkiste.app/Contents/MacOS/Wunderkiste
  Reason: image not found
```

otool output:

```
$ otool -L ~/Desktop/Wunderkiste.app/Contents/MacOS/Wunderkiste 
    @rpath/CocoaLibSpotify.framework/Versions/A/CocoaLibSpotify (compatibility version         1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 20.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1056.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 1265.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 481.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 855.11.0)
```

Project - Build Phases

[image: Xcode - Project - Build Phases]
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Runtime Search Paths` build setting in your project needs to contain `@loader_path/../Frameworks` to tell the dynamic linker where to find CocoaLibSpotify at runtime.

See [Linking and Install Names](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html) by Mike Ash for a detailed discussion.

Comment: rpath is fine (also based on that article)

Comment: No, `@rpath` won't work - try it for yourself. `@rpath` is for the framework being embedded, and `@loader_path/../Frameworks` is for the application integrating the framework, which is what the question is about.

Comment: I just checked the article again, and it looks like you misread it. Quote: "An application that intends to embed `Foo.framework` would then pass `-rpath @executable_path/../Frameworks` to the linker at build time". The `Runtime Search Paths` setting in your project is the thing that sets `-rpath`.

Comment: you are right with your _last_ comment. but the install path is @rpath as shown by the OP... only -rpath must be passed to the app that wants to use a lib from rpath... thats the cool thing. no need to modify the installname of a framework

Comment: or as a quote: "That list is embedded in the application, and can therefore be controlled by the application's build process, not the framework's. A single copy of a framework can thus work for multiple purposes."

Comment: BUT I misread your answer here ... you are right, he needs to adapt the search paths

Comment: Yes, exactly - the library is already set to `@rpath` (I know because  I wrote it :-P), and the gentleman asking the question is asking how to integrate it in his application.