# Using installed pod in swift project

Tags: swift, sockets, import, cocoapods

I'm trying to create a swift program that uses sockets. In order to do that, I'm trying to use the `SwiftSocket` library by installing it using CocoaPods. 
My `Podfile` is basic:

```
target 'socket' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    # Pods for socket
    pod 'SwiftSocket' 
end
```

According to the installation guide of `SwiftSocket`, after installing the pod I should be able to use the `TCPClient` right away.
Still, I fail to use the class in my `main.swift` file as it doesn't find the class.
I've searched the web to see what I'm missing here, but all I found are guides on how to bridge Pods written in ObjectiveC but not on pods written in Swift.

Any help?
Thanks

EDIT: With  jamshes reginahit suggestion, I've added SwiftSocket.framework to the Linked Frameworks and Libraries, in addition to the Pods_socket framework that was already present.
Now the build is successful, but I gut a runtime error of `Thread1: signal SIGABRT` with the payload:

```
yld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SwiftSocket.framework/Versions/A/SwiftSocket
  Referenced from: /Users/jonathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/socket-buglawjxihebcabvcihcbdrtkcxt/Build/Products/Debug/socket
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)
```

EDIT2: Something was funky with my Xcode. I've reinstalled it and now it seems to work fine. Thanks to everybody for the help. :)

Comment: import the lib name in top of tha class

Comment: Are you sure your pod install was successful? Do you see a `Pods_socket.framwork` under `Link Binary With Libraries` section in `Build Phases` ?

Comment: Yes I do see that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to comment, but I don't have enough reputation.
Anyway did you write something like:

```
import SwiftSocket
```

in the class where you need it? Also, did you open the project with the xcworkspace extension?
If nothing works try to clean and rebuild the project

Comment: I've tried that as well, as well as creating a new project and trying to import this, no success

Comment: Try to add it in 'Linked frameworks and Libraries' into 'General' of your project's targets

Comment: Is the library present in 'Link Binary With Libraries' into 'Build Phases'?

Comment: I personally don't have any other clue, try to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265408/cocoalibspotify-library-not-loaded)

Comment: reinstalling xcode solved the problem. import SwiftSocket is enough and works. thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on my checking of the [SwiftSocket](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket) Library, it seems that what you did should be fine (it should be pod 'SwiftSocket' referring to "Installation" section), I assume that you missed to add :

```
import SwiftSocket
```

in your `main.swift` class.

And yes, they are not mentioning that in "Code examples" section because they -probably- assume that importing it in your *.swift* file should be obvious.

Comment: It doesn't find the SwiftSocket as well (I've opened the project using the workspace created by the pod installation)

Comment: Could you check "pods" target? what does it contains?

Comment: It contains the SwiftSocket package with the swift and c files inside

Answer (score 2):

Once CocoaPods is finished installing, you need to start using the `.xcworkspace` instead of your `.xcproject` file. So close your project, open the workspace (same directory), and `import SwiftSocket`.

Comment: I've tried that, it fails to find `SwiftSocket` module

Answer (score 1):

Your `Podfile` seems correct, after that, you need to launch a terminal from your project directory:

```
cd ~/Desktop/MyProject/
```

Then run: `pod install` command.

This will create a `.xcworkspace` file and a `Pods` directory. 
Now you have to open the `.xcworkspace` file with Xcode.

Donc forget to import yout pod like this: `import SwiftSocket`

Also take a look at the CocoaPods documentation: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html